# filter a log file data from a certain time range

Tags: bash, shell, centos, sh, logfile

I want to write a script that asks user for the first and last date and time of the interval we want to filter our log data and I need some help.

I don't exactly know how to really find the data from that range as I can't use a single regex.

my log file looks like this:

```
108.162.221.147 - - [04/Aug/2016:18:59:59 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 10254 "-"...
141.101.99.235 - - [04/Aug/2016:19:00:00 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 10255 ...
108.162.242.219 - - [04/Aug/2016:19:00:00 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 10255...
185.63.252.237 - - [04/Aug/2016:19:00:00 +0200] "CONNECT...
108.162.221.147 - - [04/Aug/2016:19:00:00 +0200] "GET /?...
185.63.252.237 - - [04/Aug/2016:19:00:01 +0200] "CONNECT....
etc...
```

my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "enter the log file name  "
read fname

echo "enter the start date and time  "
read startdate

echo "enter the end fate and time  "
read enddate

result=$(some code for filtering rows from this range)
echo "$result" > 'log_results'
echo "results written into /root/log_results file"
```

I tried using

```
sed -n "/"$startdate"/,/"$enddate"/p" "fname"
```

didn't word as it couldn't see the date format because of slashes, the regex doesn't also work, as it finds only those 2 dates from log(maybe I've been writing it wrong)

how do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Usually it's best to use some kind of dedicated log parsing software for this kind of task, so that you don't have to do what you're trying to do. It's also decidedly not a job for regular expressions. However, if you must do this with text processing tools such as grep, I would suggest a two-phase approach:

1. Generate a list of every timestamp you want to find.
2. Use `grep -F` to find all lines in your log that contain one of those timestamps.

For example, if you only wanted to find the middle five lines of your file (the ones with the timestamp `[04/Aug/2016:19:00:00 +0200]`), that would make step 1 very simple (as you are generating a single-item list, with just one timestamp in it).

```
echo '[04/Aug/2016:19:00:00 +0200]' > interesting_times
```

Then find all the lines with that timestamp:

```
grep -F -f interesting_times logfile
```

You could generate a shorter list by reducing the precision of the timestamp. For example to find two entire hours of log data:

```
echo '[04/Aug/2016:19' > interesting_times
echo '[04/Aug/2016:20' >> interesting_times
```

I leave it to you to determine how to generate the list of interesting times, but seriously look into purpose-built log parsing software.